# Java heap space even use -Xmx1024m

Tags: java

In my project, I'm trying to copy a big file in DB2 and convert into Excel xlsx and iIhave a problem with

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

I tried to use -Xmx1024m, but it doesn't work. The file has 1000000 record and it stops at record 6043.

```
int index = 1;

while (rs.next()) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) index);
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        System.out.println(rs.getObject(i + 1).toString());
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) i);
        cell.setCellValue(rs.getObject(i + 1).toString());
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle2);

       // System.out.println("///// INDEX :  >>  " + index);
    }

    index++;
    
}
```

My error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize(Saver.java:1700)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.preEmit(Saver.java:1303)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emit(Saver.java:1190)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emitElement(Saver.java:962)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.processElement(Saver.java:476)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.process(Saver.java:307)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.saveToString(Saver.java:1864)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._xmlText(Cursor.java:546)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.xmlText(Cursor.java:2436)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.xmlText(XmlObjectBase.java:1500)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getKey(SharedStringsTable.java:134)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.addEntry(SharedStringsTable.java:180)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:350)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:320)
        at fileconvertorv010.GerarExcel.<init>(GerarExcel.java:121)
        at fileconvertorv011.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: How big are those `rs.getObject(i + 1).toString()` strings? There is overhead associated with each row/cell so 1 million record might need 10 GB heap.

Comment: Object getObject(int columnIndex) throws SQLException;

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }

Comment: POI’s XLSX implementation can be very memory demanding. You may try [POI’s stream API](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf)

Comment: In general, if `-Xmx1024m` doesn't work, then you need to specify a higher number, but given POIs memory requirements, that will unlikely save you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is an alternative to XSSFWorkbook, [SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html):

A new workbook can be created where you can specify the number of rows to be kept in memory. If there are more than `100` records, the first record in memory will be flushed and removed from memory, then the second one and so on (when you reach record `101` you will not have access to record `0`):

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
```

You can also keep the records in memory if you pass `-1` as a parameter to the constructor, but you might run into `OutOfMemoryError` again:

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(-1);
```